# Flexible-size arma vector allocation - true in general or is a property of Rcpp?

Tags: rcpp

I'm using Rcpp package to write a code that has the main proportion written in C++ and the smaller proportion in R.

Based on what I know from C++, all unlike R, all variables in C++ should be declared upfront and this declaration includes both type and size. For instance when we say:

```
arma::vec test(2);
```

then I assume test is an armadillo vector with size 2 which means we should not assign anything of a different size to test. Is that right?

**Here is my challenge:**

In my code, I have a loop that assigns vectors of different size (usually larger than 2) to the "test vector" **without** redeclaration of test . To my surprise, the code works perfectly fine without any compiling error !

In each iteration, here is how I assign a new vector to test:

```
test = Rcpp::as<arma::vec>(myList["aVecFromMyList"]);
```

**Question**:

Is that an Armadillo feature that we can assign vectors of different lengths to test which is initially declared to be of size 2? or it's an Rcpp package feature?

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: `arma::vec test(2);` instantiates an `arma::vec` object, where `2` has been provided to its constructor. When you later assign `test = some_other_vec;`, you discard the existing `test` and make a copy of the new vector.

Comment: @mah, please correct me if I'm wrong but for a NumericVector array, it's not possible to do the same. Can I then conclude that this an armadillo feature? If so, then all vectors in armadillo are examples of "flexible-size" arrays, right?

Comment: this is just standard C++ meaning / implementation. If there is some modification to the language to Rcpp then I'm not qualified to address the subject. So I guess the real question is: does Rcpp change the meaning (and though I know nothing of it, I would bet that it does not). Re _then all vectors in armadillo are examples of "flexible-size" arrays, right?_, essentially this is true of standard C++ vectors.

Comment: Sepehr I think you are confusing a few things and @mah is a) correct in his first answer and b) correct in pointing out that Rcpp types are not the same as Armadillo types.  And *of course* you can have dynamic memory types and reallocations in C++ -- read up on "heap versus stack" which should give a gazillion Google hits.

Comment: @Sepehr: With that, I recommend that you modify your question title as there is no _violation_ anywhere here in this question.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, thanks very much Dirk for clarification. I just changed the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking for the size of the vector to be encoded into the *type*. When you specify that something is of type `arma::vec`, you allow it to accept `arma::vec`s of any size.

If you want to enforce a size constraint in the type, then you want something like `arma::vec::fixed<N>`, where in your case `N` would be 2. This is a type that enforces the constraint that vectors should be of size `N`. There are also typedefs for low-digit versions of these, e.g. `vec2` as a fixed vector of size 2.

You would have to modify your `as` call similarly I believe -- hopefully it works, I haven't tested it.

You should read the [Armadillo docs](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat); the Armadillo docs are probably some of the cleanest and most useful out there.